# Binary or categorical image classification?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification

I have a camera pointed at a hallway, which can have one of of three states - it can be empty, it can contain my cat, and it can contain a bad cat. I'm trying to train a neural network to alert me when the camera sees the bad cat in the hallway.
I am new to machine learning and classification, so my question is - should I use a binary classification (empty/my cat vs bad cat), or should I use a 3 classes classification (empty vs my cat vs bad cat)? Which could give me better result? 
As additional information, my cat is black and the bad cat is black and white. The hallway is lit throughout the day and night, though the quality of the light changes. The images are 640 by 480, though I currently crop them to about 450 by 300.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information, you basically have three situations. However, it depends on the color set of the background. Computer vision algorithms look into distracting features and try to describe them based on their trainings. 
If for instance your hall way was red or yellow, then you will have a much easier time then having a gray hallway. That being said, since you have asked about Neural networks and keras library, there is a very famous Cat or Dog CNN network exercise under Keras. That might work well with your data set. Besides, I am not sure if your application is going to be real-time?

Comment: The background colors change with the light throughout the day, which probably makes it harder. The setup takes a picture every second if there's movement, so a second of two of analyzing is not the end of the world.